# c# how to check if a file exists in a folder using the value of a text box to add to the path

Tags: path, textbox, directory

Is it possible to take the value of a text box and add it to the directory path when searching for a file. Every suggestion requires that the name of the file is included in the path already, I need it to read it from the textBox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = textBox1.Text;
            string path = @"C:\" + fileName;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist");
            }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with your code?

Comment: It does not show that a file already exists and basically creates the same file.

Comment: Does the file actually exist? Can you debug your code and check the value of path before the if statement?